# Singleton error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this singleton to write the player name and his team name in my canvas between multiple scenes but the console shows this error: "Assets/Scripts/GlobalControl.cs(1,19): error CS8025: Parsing error". Can anyone help me to fix it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GlobalControl : MonoBehaviour 
{
private static GlobalControl instance = null;

private Text displayPlayer;
private Text displayTeam;

void Awake ()   
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        instance = this;
    }
    else if (instance != this)
    {
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
}


void Start()
{

    displayPlayer = GameObject.Find ("displayPlayer").GetComponent<Text> ();
    displayTeam = GameObject.Find ("displayTeam").GetComponent<Text> ();

    new GameSparks.Api.Requests.AccountDetailsRequest ()
        .SetDurable(true)
        .Send ((response) => {
            displayPlayer.text = response.DisplayName;
        } );

    new GameSparks.Api.Requests.GetMyTeamsRequest()
        .SetDurable(true)
        .Send(teamResp => {
            if(!teamResp.HasErrors)
            {
                foreach(var teams in teamResp.Teams)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Equipo: " + teams.TeamId);
                    displayTeam.text = teams.TeamId;

                }

            }
        } );
}
}
```

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Just to check, you have saved the script before running it?

Comment: What is gameObject? It doesn;t seem to be declared anywhere

Comment: @Johan gameObject is there when the script inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. That's no the problem.

Comment: Save the script. Save the scene. Save the project. Restart both Unity and Mono.

Comment: @Cameron This is the full error message in the Unity console

Comment: @UmairM I've done it and the error persists

Comment: @gjttt1Yes, I've done it

Comment: displayPlayer and displayTeam are 2 Text Ui placed in my canvas Panel

Comment: Is this full code? You are probably missing one of curly brackets.

Comment: @UmairM Yes, it's the full code

Comment: There is definitely some hidden character at the end of first line then. Remove first few lines and re write them (don't copy-paste).

Comment: As @UmairM stated, there has to be something going on on your file that wasn't pasted to StackOverflow. As your error message indicates, the problem is at (Line:1 Character:19).

Comment: Yes!! I've rewritten all the code and it works. ThaaaaankS !